# Space <article> <header> position fixed

Tags: html, css, header, position

I have following problem.
I'd like to have header (position:fixed) and some text in article section and between this to section some space.

My CSS code :

```
header 
{
    position: fixed

    margin-bottom: 10px; // <-- space I'd like to have
}
```

My HTML code:

```
<body>
<header> HEADER </header>

<article> SAMPLE TEXT</article>
</body>
```

But now it looks like header and article are overlapped.

http://jsfiddle.net/LvKSm/embedded/result/

So How to make this space/margin between this to section ?

Comment: could you create a quick JSFiddle with the issue?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LvKSm/

Comment: display block is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/4GAJx/) is probably what you want. You need to set a margin on the element following `header` with a value that equals the header + 10. You have to do this, because the element `header` has a position `fixed` which "removes" it from the natural flow of the document, i.e. it will sit on top of the rest of the content, and the other content ignores it. Therefore, `article` ignores the position of header and takes up its place.

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    top: 0;
}

article {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 110px; /* height header + 10px */
    background: blue;
}
```

If the height of the header is dynamic, you can set the margin-top of the article with jQuery (or JS). [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GAJx/1/).

```
$("article").css({
    "margin-top": $("header").height() + 10
});
```

Edit: I edited your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LvKSm/2/), which now works just fine.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Is it normal practice to use this code for fixed header ?

Comment: Yes it is. @AllanBradley

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `margin` on `article` tag

```
header {
    background: #ddd;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    /* width: 100%; */ /* You would probably need this */ 
}

article {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ke9KB/)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LvKSm/3/) *(Updated demo of the fiddle you created)*

---

Some Explanation, you are using `margin-bottom` on `header` tag, which is a `fixed` `position` element, now when you make any element fix, it just gets out of the document flow, and your `margin` won't have any affect on any element on your document whatsoever.

Also remember to use `top: 0;` for the `header` element or when you will use `margin-top` on `article`, it will also take `header` element along.

---

> P.S Commenting using `//` is invalid, you need to use `/* Comment goes here */`

Comment: Sometimes I can't understand people... :| nor do they often though.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do here would be applying padding-top to your body tag. [**SEE THE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LvKSm/4/)

```
body {padding-top: 120px;}
```

While also not forgetting to give `top: 0;` to your `header` tag since it has a fixed position which is also the reason why margin-bottom won't work for it.

Comment: yeah but padding top in body change every padding in document

Comment: No, it's the best thing that you could do because the top part will be always covered by the header. And by pushing that same amount from top of the body, you are not depending on other elements to give margin-top or else. Besides, padding-top is not getting applied to any other element if you are thinking so.